# Insert blob into Firebird in block statement

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I have a list with many objects which holds `byte[8]`. I want to insert them into Firebird database as a block. Without the array I can do it like this:

```
var statement = "EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN ";
foreach (var item in items)
{
   statement += "INSERT INTO table (id, val) VALUES ("
                + item.id + ", " + item.val + "); ";
}
statement += "END";
new FbCommand(statement, connection, transaction).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I want to insert into blob, I use something like this:

```
FbCommand fbc = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO table (id, blob) VALUES (@id, @blob)", connection, transaction);
fbc.Parameters.Add("@id", FbDbType.BigInt).Value = id;
fbc.Parameters.Add("@blob", FbDbType.Binary).Value = blob;
fbc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to create parametrized statement for more than one row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXECUTE BLOCK` statement can have parameters, the syntax is described in [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html):

```
EXECUTE BLOCK(blobVal BLOB = ?) AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table (id, val) VALUES (1, :blobVal);
END
```

The downside is that you have to "linearize" your parameters, ie if you have many rows you're going to have statement with many parameters (which you have to assign in another loop, so code could be quite hard to follow).

It seems that your blob data is actually very small, only 8 bytes, so perhaps an acceptable alternative is to use [binary strings](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-hexbinstrings.html) feature:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table (id, val) VALUES (1, x'01234567890ABCDEF');
END
```

This would allow you to create the EXECUTE BLOCK statement in the loop as in your first code example (ie keep it simple).

Comment: Yes, `EXECUTE BLOCK` can have parameters, but it would be really many parameters and you already wrote downsides. Binary strings looks promising. I'll give it a try. It requires conversion to string and back, but since there are no limitations (like inserting 00 in the middle of the string), it should be fine.

Comment: It works for saving and I can also create select (in FlameRobin) as written in the second link you posted. But how to get those data back to C# app? When I did row select (based on some other value), it returns me some not nice string and I am not able to convert it back into the original bytes.

Comment: Well, in your post you have byte type, not string. So do not read it back as a string but as a binary blob it is. Also, how exactly is the DB field defined (type, character set)?

Comment: I tried to define the column like this: `myColumn CHAR(8)`. Maybe I don't understand it right. I am not sure, that I am able to define, how I get the column value back from this column (bytes, not string).

Comment: For binary data one should use `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0`. In your case, if your data never exceeds 8 bytes, using blob would be overkill, so use `CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET OCTETS`

Comment: Interesting. In the second link, you posted, is written that the default character set is `OCTETS`, but if I create column as you suggests, it looks great in the FlameRobin, but not in the C#. In the result table is written, that the column is type `System.String` and in the value is string "System.Byte[]". It looks like there is some problem with conversion inside the Firebird library... Or do I have to specify something else?

Comment: IIRC if you don't specify character set for a CHAR field then database's default character set will be used. And then when you query throught C# your connection's character set will be used to convert. Conversion won't happen for OCTETS.

Comment: You are probably right. I just misunderstood that sentence in the link. Unfortunately I was not able to find any solution for the conversion. It still claims that it is `System.String`, but there was apparently `System.Byte[]`. When I work with `BLOB`, it works as expected and returns `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: Well, if the field is of type `CHAR` then from the C# point of view `string` is correct type for it. Unfortunately I don't do C# myself so I don't know how to "fool it" to treat the field as binary.

Comment: Yes, but I think that when the FlameRobin is able to convert it properly, also this library should be able to convert it properly. You still helped me a lot with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I need to save only 8 bytes and I need some solution I ended up with converting bytes into string (into hex string - each byte into two chars). I was inspired by the accepted answer.
I did this, because Firebird library for C# doesn't support conversion from column defined as `myColumn CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET OCTETS`, so I have to save bytes into string and then convert them back by myself.
It is not ideal solution, because I have to save bytes data into string (not nice part), but I need some working solution.

Comment: Interesting, I thought the Firebird .net provider did have support for `OCTETS` fields. I'll see if I can find a better solution for you.